# add discount amount field after apply the coupon code in cart page

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, discount, coupon

I want to add the discount after apply the coupon code in the cart page.I'm having the output as follows:

[image]

Now I want to add the Dsicount with its corresponding amount after **subtotal**

Thank in advance! Guide me!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discount in amount in add to cart form :

```
<input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount">
<input type="hidden" value=".50" name="discount_amount2">
```

If you are using discount in rate in add to cart form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate">
<input type="hidden" value="50" name="discount_rate2">
```

You can try this solution.

Regrads,

shahana